# Need help with Telerik RADEditor CSS issues

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik

```
<telerik:RadEditor ToolbarMode="Default"
ID="editor1" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="true">
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

The editor's using Default skin.  When I made changes to Editor.Default.CSS file they didn't reflect on my page, but when I type the following I can see the changes:

```
<link href="Skins/Default/Editor.Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Skins/Default/Window.Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<telerik:RadEditor ToolbarMode="Default"
ID="editor1" Skin="Default" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="true">
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

Do I have to create a custom Skin file for the changes to reflect?  I don't want to because the editor has been used in many files and now linking new custom CSS file in each and every .aspx file will be such a pain.  I just want this to be added in the Skin:

```
body
{
    background-image:none;
    background-color:White;
}
```

What this does is that it makes the background color of the content area white.  Earlier the content area of the Editor was inheriting background-image property of the Master Page's body tag.  Another funny issue is that the Font styles too are inheriting Master Page's properties only, like Heading 2 in the Editor's drop down list has got a background color when I want it to be simple.

So is making custom skin CSS file the only solution?  How do I get the changes to reflect through the Default CSS file only? I don't want to create a custom class.  Why didn't the changes reflect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want the editor to inherit the CSS from the main page, you should tell it which CSS classes are to be loaded in the content area (iframe). See the [external CSS](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/externalcssfiles.html) help article and probably the [CSS dropdown](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/cssstyles.html) article as well. Finally, there is a separate page for content area CSS troubleshooting - [content area appearance problems](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-content-area-appearance-problems.html)

Comment: okk..so if I don't want my Master Page's CSS to screw up my RADEditor..I need to include this telerik:EditorCssFile in every file that's got this editor embedded...right ? I can't do something inside of this one Editor.Default.css to make it work fine ?

Comment: Yes, the ContentAreaCssFile property or CssFiles collection should be set on the RadEditor control. If you want to keep the changes in a single place, you can use something similar to ASP.NET Themes ( http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/usingthemes.html ) or subclass the RadEditor and use the derived class in your pages.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your body `background-color` is not overwritten in the Window.Default.css. Always the last entry in a CSS file or a subsequent file takes precedence over the one before. Try going for `background-color:white !important;`.
Adding `!important` after any CSS rule will make it just that and override any precedence.

As for why the changes didn't reflect: Check which styles the Telerik control is actually using. Check the Source of the page and check the references CSS files whether they have your added properties - maybe there are some other CSS files creeping around in some cache?

Your tool of choice to check the styles for a specific element might be the Internet Explorer (if you're using IE) Developer Toolbar - just hit F12 and select the Telerik Editor with the little arrow and you will see all associated styles and where they came from.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that worked for me was to set these properties on the editor:

```
ContentAreaMode="Div"
CssClass="wysiwygeditor"
```

then in CSS you can override what you need

```
.wysiwygeditor { background-color: white; background-image: none; }
```

It would be nice if Telerik would expose a property to set a class on the body element when using `ContentAreaMode=Iframe` instead of `Div`, both CKeditor and TinyMCE support a property like that and it makes it possible to easily remove the unwanted body styles while still supporting most of the page CSS in the editor.

Comment: There is a property you can use in Iframe mode, called ContentAreaCssFile. Set it to a CSS file in your web site and it will be loaded in the RadEditor content area. With this property, no default RadEditor styles will be used and you can define your own in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit an xml config file (in my case it is named ConfigDefault.xml).

In the `<configuration/>` node you can add something like the following to load the css of your choice to apply to the content (html document) that is loaded ***within*** the iframe:

```
<configuration>
    <property name="CssFiles">one.css,two.css</property>
      ...more items
</configuration>
```

So if you need one.css for your regular site css, then two.css can perform the override to remove the background image / change the background colour.